# ftrace into serial console during reboot

Tags: linux-kernel, ftrace

I'm debugging the very late stages of kernel reboot (right after ACPI: PM: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5), and I want to see a trace there.

I want to enable ftrace for a rarely called function `acpi_sleep_prepare` (so there going to be not much of the noise), but I need to see it on serial console, because everything else is dead by that moment.

Are there a way to force ftrace to log into serial console? If not, what can I do to get trace for that (late shutdown) function?

Comment: HAve you used `no_console_suspend` kernel command line parameter? Does it help?

Comment: Thank you, I've tried it, but it does not help. I'm debugging reboots, so it does not influence reboot code, I think.

Comment: It does but exactly to the moment when driver got frozen / suspended. Since it's about ACPI, you may enable ACPI & ACPICA debugging (IIRC it can be done via `acpi_debug` kernel command line parameter, don't remember if it requires a kernel configuration to be enabled for that). It might give little bit more. But in general as @matt suggested, you will require a HW debugger at this point. Also depends on the platform the actual issue may lie in the EC firmware.

Answer (score 1):

Why not writing a simple module and using printk ? kmsg could be redirected outward via serial or network.

Since you are trying to trace system reboots, using hardware auxiliaries like JTAG or DCI (for Intel CPUs) would be more effective。

Comment: I've tried. Then I found that even a small output in printk is lagging behind the actual hanging (e.g. I can see some line on the console, but not on the serial, because by the time kernel got to the printing a specific line at 115200 , system is already hang).

Well, I guess, printk across the code with delay loops is the single option here...